# How to know if an `InputMethod` is enabled?

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am writing a custom `InputMethod` from scratch and would like to show the user a button in my `Activity` to enable my `InputMethod` in case it is disabled...

I would need to find out programmatically if my `InputMethod` is enabled in the device or not.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InputMethodManager` to get the list of enabled `InputMethodInfo` and iterate over it to find out if your `InputMethod` is enabled or not.

```
public boolean isMyInputMethodEnabled() {
    boolean isEnabled = false;

    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager
            = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    List<InputMethodInfo> inputMethodList = inputMethodManager
            .getEnabledInputMethodList();

    for (InputMethodInfo inputMethodInfo : inputMethodList) {
        if (inputMethodInfo.getPackageName().equals(getPackageName())) {
            isEnabled = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isEnabled;
}
```